# Large jpegs become blurred when printing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am saving large 8 x 12 inch picture to disk as JPEG, the file is 35 megabytes when opened in Photoshop only 1.5 MB on disk when printing out the picture, and it prints blurred.

It seems to loose quality when saving as a JPEG file. Any suggestions?

Comment: All thoose units do not say anithing at all, Disk space, file weight.

Answer (score -2):

Mabe you got to low DPI ? In print to format A3 the normal DPI it's 300.

Comment: dpi is 300, I emailed the jpegs to phone before printing so perhaps it was email compressing them maybe?

Comment: But in 300 dpi if you will zoom image to 100% it's still sharp ? If it's not, so image it's to small for print in that kind of format. Or mabe print machine doesent print a HD image ? can you put here this image ?